# Could not find a valid GoogleService-lnfo.plist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image]

```
'`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
```

I already try to replace a new GoogleService-Info.plist to my project but it still having the same problem.

Comment: Where do you put the `plist` file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]Make sure your plist file is:

- Downloaded from your Firebase project
- Added to Copy Bundle Resources (Choose your target -> Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources)

Or try to add that file from Menu as below
[image]

I see the log states that No app has been configured yet.
[image]

Let's try add these lines of code in the beginning of your `AppDelegate`

```
if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
    let firbaseOptions = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: path!)
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: firbaseOptions!)
}
```

Comment: I added to Copy Bundle Resources but it still have the same problem. Can I know  (Choose your target -> Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources) that you mention is need to do at which part?

Comment: After you add the plist file into your profile, dont forget to choose Copy Items if needed and select the right target when you add that file

Comment: I have selected 'Copy Item If Needed'. It doesn't ask for select target but I have set the target at 'Deployment Info'

Comment: Okay, then let's remove the current plist file, then try to add it from your project folder's option menu (I updated the answer, lets check the last attached image)

Comment: Or try to add it to Compile Sources:Choose your target -> Build Phase -> Compile Sources

Comment: Did it but sorry it still having the same problem. Actually my project I didn't use drag and drop function, I fully code the whole project did i still need the MainStoryboard?

Comment: Didnt use drag and drop is not the problem. Your plist file might not be added to compile sources. Let's try restarting your Xcode and repeat above steps and see if it works.

Comment: I restarted my xCode and it still didn't work. Now the whole application will terminating when I run. If I remove 'FirebaseApp.configure()' then it can run but when I need to connect to Firebase function it will terminating again.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check the last section, @Ice

Comment: Now my app can run. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from the Firebase console.

To do so, go your console home. Click the `settings icon` next to the `Project Overview` in the left nav bar. Then scroll down and find this dialog:[image]

From there, download and add to your root directory within xcode and the error should disappear.

Comment: I tried few times but it still have the same problem. This way doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

At first, you have to create a Firebase Project in https://console.firebase.google.com/
[Create project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fr1h.png)

Then follow the following steps to download the "GoogleService-lnfo.plist" file.[Project is ready for next steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho31f.png)

Now,[Choose iOS option here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm9kT.png)

Give your Bundle Identifier and project name here.[Press on Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTb8S.png)

Download the "GoogleService-lnfo.plist" file and drag and drop to your project.[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgBrY.png)

Now Most importantly, If you do not install the pod with "Firebase" then you can not use it as "import Firebase". So, install or update the pod file.
[Install pod file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEWtE.png)

Finally, add this line in your AppDelegate.swift file.

Like this

```
import UIKit
import Firebase // pod must be installed to use Firebase
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: 
Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()// This line is must be added.
        return true
    }
}
```

Done !!! Have a nice Swifty day.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete google services file from file insepector in Xcode
2. Delete its reference name from Build phases
3. Drag and drop google services info plist again and a popup will appear mark check button and radio buttons like in below picture 
   [image]